# spacy - 3.1 custom loss function and data augmentation for named entity recognition for imbalanced data

Tags: named-entity-recognition, imbalanced-data, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

how to write a custom custom loss function for named entity recognition for imbalanced data in spacy v3 and above. My dataset contains imbalanced data for labels. For example: label a has 45000 annotations, label b has only 4000 annotations. How to do augmentation and write custom loss function in spacy.

Comment: If you want to use a custom loss function you'll need to write a custom component but that's pretty involved - you can't just swap out loss functions in the default spaCy components. For augmentation please see the section on augmentation in the official docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please suggest oversampling / under sampling techniques for imbalanced data for named entity recognition using spacy.

Comment: @sampathkumaran Have you found any answers to oversampling/undersampling techniques using spaCy? Could you share it please?

Comment: @polm23 Are there oversampling / undersampling techniques that should be applied using spaCy? or is SMOTE and NearMiss expected to be applied? Thank you.